# EF Core Group On Nav Properties

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Quick question regarding this issue.
I have an error unable to get the data from database,
Is there something issue with EF Core or my linq query?

```
var query = _postRepository.Table
    .Where(x => x.Approval == true)
    .Include(p => p.Industry)
    .GroupBy(grp => new { grp.Industry.Id, grp.Industry.Name })
    .Select(s => new JobPostStatistics
    {
         IndustryId = s.Key.Id,
         IndustryName = s.Key.Name,
         TotalJobPost = s.Count()
    });

return query.Take(6).ToList();
```

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Comment: Are you sure that's where you get that error? That error is caused by `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: It is hard to deduce where the problem is coming from. The query seems ok. Could you please show your code for JobPostStatistics?

Comment: That the query when you try to .list or .singleordefault it encounter the error invalidoperatinexception so thinking it is error on ef core?

Answer (score 1):

Seems in EF RC1 `GroupBy` cause error, here is reported bug:

[`GroupBy` query cause error `Sequence contains more than one element`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4775)

Answer (score 1):

EF [Core 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#ef-core-20) will not only work, but it will also be capable of translating `GroupBy` to SQL `GROUP BY`. The expected release date is [Q4 2017](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap). Previous versions also support `GroupBy` but execute it on the client side, which can be a huge problem if you're using it to retrieve aggregates, like `SUM`, from the database. *Imagine retrieving 2 million rows from the server to calculate the sum on the client side, instead of getting it directly from the database server*.

In the meantime, you can always write your own SQL query and map it to an entity or anonymous type, using `DbSet.FromSql`, i.e. invoking `FromSql` as a member of an entity collection of your context.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have enabled eager loading by using include keyword. You try with disable lazy loading

Comment: I state it "Ef Core", eager loading doesn't support on EF Core that why I need to use .Include the navigation properties

Comment: If you use include you are enabling eager loading

Answer (score 0):

Server-side GroupBy-support of EF Core has been postponed to after the release: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341
When you log the queries EF creates you can see that it does not create GROUP BY in the SQL.

Here somebody else posted the same error with another GroupBy query.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4775

I had another error with GroupBy and Include(). As EF does not support GroupBy in the SQL and the grouping is done on the client side, I split my query into a server side part and a client side part. The first part queries from the database with the Include() into an anonymous type. Then I do the grouping on the client side.

```
var event2Country = DbContext.Event2Countries
    .Include(j => j.Location)
    .Select(j => new { j.Location.Id, j.Location.Name })
    .AsNoTracking();
viewModel.MostUsedCountries = event2Country
    .GroupBy(j => new { j.Id, j.Name })
    .OrderByDescending(j => j.Count())
    .ThenBy(j => j.Key.Id)
    .Select(j => new SimpleListCountViewModel()
    {
        Id = j.Key.Id,
        Name = j.Key.Name,
        Count = j.Count()
    })
    .Take(15)
    .ToList();
```

Currently you cannot use GroupBy in EF Core if you have a lot of data. A workaround would be to use FromSql. See issue 4959 on Github.